# filling a list with a series of known elements

Tags: racket

Is there a quicker way to write the following code?

```
(list var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 ... var100)
```

Basically all the elements are variables with prefix "var".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a macro:

```
#lang racket
(require syntax/parse/define (for-syntax racket/syntax))
(define-simple-macro (varN-range var:id arg:number ...)
  #:with [varN ...]
  (for/list ([N (apply in-range (syntax->datum #'(arg ...)))])
    (format-id #'var "~a~a" #'var N))
  (list varN ...))
```

Using it:

```
> (define var1 "a")
> (define var2 "b")
> (define var3 "c")
> (define var4 "d")
> (define var5 "e")
> (varN-range var 1 6)
(list "a" "b" "c" "d" "e")
```