# Racket SQL: how to use variable value as table name in create-table?

Tags: racket

https://docs.racket-lang.org/sql/ is a nice DSL for preparing SQL statements, which works with the `db` library.

The docs show an example like:

```
(require sql)

(create-table #:temporary the_numbers
  #:columns [n integer #:not-null] [d varchar])
```

In this code `the_numbers` is not an identifier, it's treated literally as the name of the table.

What I want to do is something like:

```
(require sql)

(define (my-create-table table-name)
  (create-table #:temporary table-name
    #:columns [n integer #:not-null] [d varchar]))
```

This gives an error because it treats `table-name` as the actual table name and it doesn't like the hyphen in it (I think it should be possible to use that as a table name but I guess I need to do something more to have the lib quote it properly...)

I am new to Racket and don't know many tricks. I tried using `'table-name` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Not super helpful, I know, but I think you're going to need a macro to do what you want to do (i.e. `my-create-table` is going to be a macro I think). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63120915/filling-a-list-with-a-series-of-known-elements) seems like it could be useful - I'll try a few things out and post an answer if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The features you need are described in the [Dynamic Statement Composition and SQL Injection](https://docs.racket-lang.org/sql/index.html#%28part._escapes%29) of the docs. You can write the *Ident* for the table's name as `(Ident:AST ,expr)`, where `expr` produces an Ident AST value.

```
> (define (my-create-table table-name)
    (create-table #:temporary (Ident:AST ,(make-ident-ast table-name))
      #:columns [n integer #:not-null] [d varchar]))
> (my-create-table 'the_numbers)
(sql-statement
 "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE the_numbers (n integer NOT NULL, d varchar)")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Even with the link I still can't deduce this solution from the docs, though to be fair I am new to Racket. Don't you feel there's maybe a bit too much macro magic going on here, that we have to jump through such hoops just to use the _value_ of a variable (like in any normal code) instead of its _name_ ...?

Comment: I think the macro hoop-jumping is mostly of `create-table`'s creation - it's a weird macro in the first place that takes an id rather than an expression for some reason. The hoops you jump through here are mostly to undo that I think

Comment: You can think of the various `sql` macros as versions of `quasiquote` that check the structure of their contents at compile time. They support dynamically inserting ASTs using `unquote` (in some places), but they require you to say what kind of AST you plan to put there. One could imaging inferring that, but I think sometimes it might be ambiguous, and I think it's better to be explicit anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that should work for you:

```lisp
#lang racket

(require syntax/parse/define)
(require sql)

(define-simple-macro (my-create-table table-name:id)
  (create-table #:temporary table-name
                #:columns [n integer #:not-null] [d varchar]))

(my-create-table my_table_name)
```

This creates a macro called `my-create-table`. What that essentially does is it syntactically replaces (hygienically) the expression `(my-create-table <some-id>)`, where `<some-id>` is any identifier, with the expression below (the `create-table` expression), replacing `table-name` with the id given in the original syntax.

Macros are cool.

Comment: Great! ...I didn't think an excuse for using macros would arrive so soon on my journey with Racket :)

Comment: How could we modify this so it accepts either a string/symbol literal or an identifier, and has a default (literal) value?

Comment: Hmm. For the default value, I think you'll need to dive into the more powerful `define-syntax`/`syntax-rules` to define two separate rules - one which has a param and one which doesn't. I'll take a look at the string/symbol thing and post an update to my answer when I figure that out.

Comment: BTW I think this doesn't work at the moment: `> (define tblname "hashtable")
> (my-create-table tblname)
(sql-statement "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tblname (n integer NOT NULL, d varchar)")`

Comment: right, I think it has to do with the `:id` bit I have. Let me try removing that and see what happens. It's currently looking for an identifier, not any expression